# Slider images taking time to load.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Live site- http://newedgeindustries.ca

I use [pgwSlider](http://pgwjs.com/pgwslider/) for homepage slider, everything is ok except slider image reload every time in Chrome while changing one image to another.

Any idea how to fix that issue.

Same thing works perfectly here- http://arif-khan.net/project/web_aceive/index.html

Code:

```
<ul class="pgwSlider">
  <li><img src="images/_big-image1.jpg" alt="" data-description="" ></li>
  <li><img src="images/_big-image2.jpg" alt="" data-description="" ></li>
  <li><img src="images/_big-image3.jpg" alt="" data-description="" ></li>
  <li><img src="images/_big-image4.jpg" alt="" data-description="" ></li>
  <li><img src="images/_big-image5.jpg" alt="" data-description="" ></li>
</ul>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.pgwSlider').pgwSlider();
 });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Use some sort of lazy loading script.

Comment: strange behavior. maybe you want to use another one?

Comment: Same thing works perfectly here- http://www.arif-khan.net/project/web_aceive/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are unable to replicate the issue and the images are taking time to load, the better option is to **compress the images**.

The images you have used are of **JPG** format and size **ranging 130 Kb to 200 Kb** and more.

You can compress them here at **[JPG compressor](http://jpeg-optimizer.com/)**. This compresses the image up to **80%** and the quality is also maintained.

The same worked for me once.